# Uncaught TypeError and Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am completely helpless with this issue that I am having.

The code on my site showed the guitar tabs of the songs once you placed your mouse on them. The tabs were triggered using the onMouseMove option.

Now they are not showing. It is showing the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" and "Uncaught ReferenceError: obj is not defined".

Is there any way that I could bring that option back?
You can find the page at 
http://www.chordzone.org/2016/04/eric-church-record-year.html

The javascript that I used for showing the tabs are at:

What can I do to fix this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

The function is called here:

```
 var lcnt=64;var chords=new Array();var freds=new Array();var alts=new Array();var js_sins=new Array();var sk_chords=new Array();
 chords["Bb"]= "113331";freds["Bb"]= "1";alts["Bb"]= "......";
 chords["Cm"]= "113321";freds["Cm"]= "3";alts["Cm"]= "......";
 chords["Gm"]= "133111";freds["Gm"]= "3";alts["Gm"]= "......";
 chords["F"]= "133211";freds["F"]= "1";alts["F"]= "......";
 chords["Eb"]= "143121";freds["Eb"]= "3";alts["Eb"]= "......";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/883ngy3z/

Comment: Please post the relevant code here.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I've added the code

Answer (score 0):

You got two bugs.

1- Probably a scope issue in the block of :

```
if (isNetscape4)
```

2- The `parse_chords(r)` function your `var s` is the issue. I cant know the error since you posted unformated and probably missing code.

Those are the sources of your bugs.

Comment: I've added the code. Please tell me how to fix these issues. You help is really appreciated